# Revisión de edición de Wiki de Etiqueta - contenido copiado

Tags: discusión

En varias ocasiones he rechazado ediciones de Wikis de etiqueta porque el contenido es una copia (usualmente de la Wikipedia) **que no contiene la atribución** requerida por la licencia bajo la que ha sido publicado.

Por ejemplo esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tiene el texto (casi) exacto del artículo de la Wikipedia [Teclado (Informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teclado_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

> En informática, un teclado es un dispositivo o periférico de entrada, en parte inspirado en el teclado de las máquinas de escribir, que utiliza una disposición de botones o teclas, para que actúen como palancas mecánicas o interruptores electrónicos que envían información a la computadora.
>
> Después de las tarjetas perforadas y las cintas de papel, la interacción a través de los teclados, al estilo teletipo, se convirtió en el principal dispositivo de entrada para las computadoras.

Cuya licencia es [Creative Commons Atribución Compartir Igual 3.0](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Texto_de_la_Licencia_Creative_Commons_Atribuci%C3%B3n-CompartirIgual_3.0_Unported)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas ediciones vienen de uno o dos usuarios en particular.

Tomando como hecho que mi proceder es correcto (por favor corrijanme si me equivoco), ahora me salta la inquietud

- Creo que el sistema debiera bloquear la capacidad de los usuarios que relizan ediciones que son rechazadas.
- ¿Debiera notificar a un moderador para que actúe en este caso y quizás le de una advertencia al usuario?
- ¿El usuario puede ver que sus ediciones han sido rechazadas y el motivo?

p.d. Luego de escribir este post, he rechazado 3 ediciones al hilo por la misma razón, del mismo usuario.

[edición]

He editado la pregunta para resaltar el hecho que el motivo de mi publicación es la falta de atribución, y no el hecho de utilizar el texto como tal, siempre y cuando esté permitido por el autor. Por lo mismo he añadido información sobre la licencia y atribución requerida en el caso de marras.

Comment: ¿Por qué debería ser incorrecto usar la definición de la Wikipedia para el contenido de una etiqueta? Si consideramos la W como fuente válida y contando que es difícil o imposible aportar nada más a dicha definición ¿Por qué rechazar la edición de la etiqueta? Puede que alguno piense que son usuarios intentando ganar puntos "*inmoralmente*" pero no veo nada de inmoral en ampliar los datos de SOes siempre que se haga bien, venga de donde venga la información.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @PaperBirdMaster. No veo nada de malo en usar definiciones de la Wikipedia mientras se respete la licencia.

Comment: @PaperBird, el problema, como hago ver en la pregunta, es justamente que no se está dando la atribución requerida por la licencia de la Wikipedia. Yo tampoco veo problema en que se utilice el texto, siempre que se haga apropiadamente.

Comment: Es cierto, dices que es una copia sin atribución, había entendido mal y creía que te parecía mal que se sacara de la wikipedia la información, me pasa por leer demasiado rápido. En ese caso has actuado correctamente @jachguate.

Comment: @jachguate "*no veo nada inmoral en ampliar los datos de SOes [con información de la Wikipedia] siempre que se haga bien*".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: He editado la pregunta para resaltar el tema de la atribución, que es lo que realmente me motivó a escribirla en un inicio.

Comment: @jachguate Perfecto :) mucho más claro ahora. Gracias.

Comment: @blonfu Yo tampoco lo veo inmoral, he editado la pregunta para hacer más claro mi punto, que es justamente ese, el de _hacerlo bien_

Answer (score 4):

Resumen: esto se puede bloquear automáticamente. Si los revisores se fijan bien al revisar no hará falta que los moderadores lo hagan manualmente.

> - Creo que el sistema debiera bloquear la capacidad de los usuarios que relizan ediciones que son rechazadas.

Estoy de acuerdo.

De hecho esto es automático. Como se explica en [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/209901), si en los últimos 7 días de actividad `(ediciones rechazadas - (ediciones aprobadas / 3)) >= 5`, se genera un bloqueo automático.

Más información sobre la sugerencia de edición en [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/209901).

> - ¿Debiera notificar a un moderador para que actúe en este caso y quizás le de una advertencia al usuario?

Cuando veas algo sospechoso que no puedas solucionar con las herramientas que tu reputación te da, usa los reportes para comunicarlo a los moderadores. Ellos tienen multitud de herramientas adicionales que permiten atajar los problemas con mejor perspectiva y limpieza.

> - ¿El usuario puede ver que sus ediciones han sido rechazadas y el motivo?

Sí. Toda sugerencia de edición genera una página, que en este caso está disponible en https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23553. En ella todo el mundo puede ver la sugerencia, así como quién la revisó y qué acción tomó.

En el caso del usuario, puede verse su historial de sugerencias a través de su perfil en [*Todas las acciones > Sugerencias*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/17469/randall-sandoval?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Navegar un poco por ella da fe de que poca gente se tomó la molestia de detener la copia compulsiva de contenido sin atribución que hizo este usuario. Es una pena, pues existe la opción de rechazo *Esta edición copia una cantidad significativa de contenido de una fuente externa...* que tú elegiste.

En Stack Overflow existen pruebas aleatorias de revisión que sirven para verificar que la gente está revisando correctamente. Más info en [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/209901). Tal y como indica nuestro moderador Miquel Coll en los comentarios, actualmente no existen en SOes. No sería mala idea incorporarlos.

Como comentario adicional, los moderadores tienen la potestad de bloquear a un usuario para que no pueda revisar las colas de revisión durante un tiempo determinado. Puedes ver la descripción en Meta Stack Exchange: [Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/209901).

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Me gustaría añadir que actualmente **NO** tenemos review audits en SOes. Hice un [post](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/796/7242) hace un tiempo y no se llegó a nada definitivo.

Comment: @MiquelColl ah, qué bueno saberlo. He editado la respuesta para reflejar tu comentario, gracias.