# Ya nos graduamos, habiliten los audits en las colas de revision

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, revisiones, auditorías-de-revisión

Acabo de revisar y rechazar una edicion sugerida pesima, que claramente conflictuaba con la intencion del autor.

Fui al historial a ver como quedo la revison (felizmente rechazada) y note que tenia un voto de aprobacion. No hace falta dar nombres, toda la informacion es publica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claramente se le han escapado cosas... 0 de 126?

No estoy seguro porque no se han habilitado los audits aun, ya que se pidio varias veces (falta citar aqui)

Pero en un sentido practico, los audits de colas de revision evitarian estas situaciones mejorando la calidad de contenido y enseñando.

Los audits enseñan.. a mi me funcionaron otrora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I apologize for using English here, but my Spanish is a bit rusty. I've turned on audits for this site making it just the ninth site with this feature. Only our [most active sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) benefit from audits. Please let me know if anything breaks or seems weird.

---

Traducción automatizada:

Me disculpo por usar el inglés aquí, pero mi español está un poco oxidado. He activado las auditorías para este sitio, convirtiéndolo en el noveno sitio con esta función. Solo nuestros [sitios más activos](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday) se benefician de las auditorías. Por favor, háganmelo saber si algo se rompe o parece extraño.

Comment: That's great news!! Thanks a lot, we've been waiting for this for years :)

Comment: There is a little bug, @Jon [Las auditorías de revisión no aparecen en el historial del perfil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3726/83). That is, the audit review do not show in the activity tab or the user profile.

Answer (score 13):

Esto es algo que se ha pedido múltiples veces:

- [Introducción de los review audits](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/854/introducci%C3%B3n-de-los-review-audits)
- [Un gran poder conlleva una gran responsabilidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/796/un-gran-poder-conlleva-una-gran-responsabilidad)
- [Un comentario.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165/revisi%C3%B3n-de-edici%C3%B3n-de-wiki-de-etiqueta-contenido-copiado#comment2950_1167)
- [Otro comentario.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1833/cerrado-por-demasiado-amplio-usado-para-preguntas-de-baja-calidad/1835#comment5264_1835)
- [Mención a los review audits que sí existen en el sitio ruso.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/804/301)
- [Respuesta de fedorqui a ¿Qué criterio siguen ustedes al manejar las colas de revisión para votos de cierre y reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1259/301)

Pero por parte del representante de SO (Juan M) no ha habido respuesta ni a favor ni en contra. Que yo recuerde, si alguien la conoce que la cite, por favor.
Yo creo que la mayoría de usuarios está a favor de los audits. Pero da igual lo que hablemos al respecto pues esto solo se puede hacer con soporte del personal de SO. Pero desde SO ni siquiera han estado dispuestos a hablar del tema.

Comment: `Pero da igual lo que hablemos al respecto pues esto solo se puede hacer con soporte del personal de SO`.. un poco mas de optimismo, vamos!!

Comment: @EmanuelVe Yo soy muy optimista. Soy tan optimista que pese a que nunca han respondido yo sigo y sigo y sigo insistiendo con la esperanza de que algún día tengamos review audits. Pero la pelota no está en nuestro tejado.

Comment: También hablé de ello en [¿Qué criterio siguen ustedes al manejar las colas de revisión para votos de cierre y reapertura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1259/83)