# ¿Se podría ampliar el número de votos en las colas de revisión?

Tags: característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, colas-de-revisión

A menudo me encuentro con el problema de que los 20 votos por cada cola de revisión es molesto, ya que me gustaría poder revisar todas las preguntas/respuestas posibles y evitar que se tengan que dar preguntas del tipo: [Febrero 2018 - ¿un mes de revisiones malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/febrero-2018-un-mes-de-revisiones-malas#comment11889_3284)

Sin embargo, aún es más molesto cuando haber llegado al límite de votos desde una cola de revisión te implica que no puedas revisar en otras colas de revisión.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, yo he completado los 20 votos diarios de la cola de revisión de cierre de preguntas, pero no he completado los 20 votos de la cola de revisión de Primeras publicaciones.

Sin embargo, como la publicación es mala y la quiero cerrar por el motivo X, no puedo y le tengo que dar a la opción de **Omitir**, ya que no es que **No se requiera ninguna acción**, si no que simplemente no puedo realizarla.

Creo que se debería hacer algo al respecto, ya que esto implica que si completas todos los votos que tienes para el cierre de preguntas, te limita mucho en el resto de colas de revisión y, por lo tanto, **se alarga todavía más el tiempo en el que las preguntas pasan el proceso de revisión.**

En relación a esto tengo dos preguntas:

- ¿Se podría ampliar el número de votos diarios en las colas de revisión?
- ¿Se podría hacer que el límite de votos de una cola de revisión no afectara en el resto de colas de revisión?

Comment: Hay un detalle para aclarar, que no cambia en nada tu propuesta: el [límite de votos de cierre diario es **24**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), y es un valor global que no está necesariamente atado a la cola de cierre... Aunque cerrar en la cola de cierre te quita un voto, son valores independientes. Por ejemplo, si emitiera 24 votos de cierre directamente en preguntas (fuera de cualquier cola), también pasaría lo mismo.

Comment: @Mariano Sí, por eso yo creo que tendría que cambiarse el sistema para agilizar las colas de revisión. Por ejemplo, que los 20 votos fueran por cola de revisión en vez de globales creo que podría ser una buena solución.

Comment: está perfecto, entendí. Sólo comenté (diciendo "*que no cambia en nada tu propuesta*") porque se podía malinterpretar. La explicación que se dio a este límite era para mantener un máximo lógico para cada usuario (lo que está bien que se haga en un día y evitar abusos). En cuanto a lo que estás proponiendo, yo llego seguido al límite, pero estoy indeciso sobre qué hacer con esto (espero a ver cómo sigue el tema).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Lo que debemos ampliar es el número de personas que revisan.

Llevemos al extremo la ampliación de número de votos: que cada cual pueda votar tanto como pueda: los que ya ayudan ayudarán más y no se verá el problema. Tal y como nos mostró Mariano hace unos días en [Febrero 2018 - ¿un mes de revisiones malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3284/83):

> solamente **23 usuarios** son los responsables del **85% del total** de todas las revisiones.

Esto es un drama, pues de una forma u otra las colas cogerán las costumbres de estas pocas personas. Es mejor darle aire, que entren nuevas personas, que opinen diferente, que lo comenten en Meta y se genere un círculo virtuoso de mejora de la gestión de las publicaciones.

¡Ojo! No pongo en entredicho lo que están haciendo esos 23 valientes hasta la fecha, mi agradecimiento es total :) Simplemente creo que es injusto que una comunidad con decenas de miles de usuarios dependa en buena medida de la disponibilidad de una treintena de personas.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, hay que seguir insistiendo en el tema de votar mas frecuentemente. Necesitamos mas revisores, cuantos mas mejor. Y extiendo el agradecimiento a ti, que eres parte de los 23 magníficos ;)

Comment: ¿Y que se te ocurre para poder "enganchar" a nuevas personas para que entren a las colas de revisión?