# ¿Qué acción tomar en la revisión de reapertura de ❝¿Como saber la UUID Android?❞?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, pregunta-específica

En la cola de reapertura, analicé a https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/89427.

La [pregunta en cuestión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/149447/127):

> **¿Como saber la UUID Android? [en espera]**
>
> ---
>
> tengo una pregunta directa, ¿como puedo saber cual es el identificador unico universal del puerto bluetooth en android?
>
> Estoy intentando conectar un módulo HC-06 con una aplicacion en Android-Studio y me gustaría saber la UUID de mi servidor (smartphone), un saludo y gracias de antemano
>
> ---
>
> [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [android-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) [arduino](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino)

Es una pregunta que parece muy directa, va al punto, y luego de la edición no deja lugar a dudas sobre lo que está preguntando. Claramente es un usuario nuevo, no sólo por su reputación sino por el saludo (que asumo que el sistema eliminó dejando a la primera oración en minúscula) y el agradecimiento al final.

Se le podría cuestionar que no está mostrando su código, pero ¿acaso el desconocimiento de qué método usar no implica que no haya realmente nada de código para mostrar? Al fin y al cabo, está preguntando por un método específico, no una corrección de código sobre un error.

Podría haber mencionado un poco qué investigó y, si bien no creo que sea suficiente, veo que el autor [comentó](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149447/como-saber-la-uuid-android#comment279863_149447):

> he buscado información de la UUID, y si no estoy equivocado, cada dispositivo ''tiene'' una UUID, pero lo que no he visto es como poder saber cual es

además, tampoco me parece que sea totalmente evidente cómo sacarlo leyendo [Bluetooth](http://Bluetooth) o [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html).

Veo que el autor está respondiendo activamente a los comentarios, lo cual es muy bueno... En definitiva, me pareció que era una buena candidata para que **algún experto en Android le haga una buena edición y la salve**.

---

Estaba inclinándome a votar por reabrir, y quizás comentar recomendándole a alguno de los que ya habían comentado si no les parecía bien editar la pregunta para que esté en un formato más aceptable.

Sin embargo, luego vi que a posteriori se publicó la pregunta [¿Como obtener el UUID de bluetooth en un dispositivo Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/149536/127). Entonces, si fuera a reabrirla, ¿sería solamente para marcarla como duplicada?

Omití la revisión, pero acá va mi pregunta:
¿Cómo creen que debería haber procedido en la revisión de esta pregunta?

Comment: Me parece que Jorge hizo esa pregunta justamente para poder poner una respuesta. creo que debemos dejarla cerrada, reabriarla para cerrarla como duplicada me parece un gasto de esfuerzo innecesario. Igual el que mejor puede contestar esto, es Jorge

Comment: @gbianchi "creo que debemos dejarla cerrada". La pregunta no está cerrada sino que está en espera. Lamentablemente hay impacientes que no saben esperar.

Comment: @Jose al igual que gbianchi, yo también utilizo el término *cerrada* tanto para las recientes (*en espera*) como para las que tienen más de 5 días... ¿Es importante la distinción? -Por supuesto! Así como tampoco creo que sea lo mismo una puesta en espera hace 10 minutos, 1 día, 5, 15 o 1 año... Creo que el término "*cerrada*" aplica a todas, pero ya entraríamos en una discusión de qué término usar que creo que no aporta nada, mientras tengamos en claro los tiempos y las acciones que trascurrieron.

Comment: @Mariano tienes razón. Tendría que haber dicho: la pregunta está cerrada pero además está en espera. Lamentablemente hay quien no sabe esperar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En cuanto a esta pregunta puedo comentar que como moderadores consultamos entre nosotros acerca de ciertas preguntas para determinar si estas podrían ser validas o no, en este caso especifico se me consulto a mí sobre que opinaba sobre la validez de esta pregunta o si tenía una respuesta, por eso requerimos OP proporcionar más detalles.

Comentas que:
"Es una pregunta que parece muy directa, va al punto, y luego de la edición no deja lugar a dudas sobre lo que está preguntando."

La pregunta es "muy directa" (¿Como saber la UUID Android?) pero hay varias dudas con respecto a lo que pregunta, comento varios puntos acerca de esta pregunta:

> - Se pregunta sobre el UUID pero este puede ser del dispositivo o del puerto bluetooth, lo cual pregunta nuestro compañero @Einer.
> - El dispositivo puede obtener UUID de otros usuarios conectados en "pairing mode".
> - El OP no estaba seguro sobre si requería una IP o el numero de 16 bytes.
> - Se puede obtener la UUID del propio dispositivo pero solo por reflexión.
> - Incluso bluetooth del dispositivo puede tener varios identificadores!.
> - Esta intentando conectar un [HC-06](http://www.naylampmechatronics.com/blog/15_Configuraci%C3%B3n--del-m%C3%B3dulo-bluetooth-HC-06-usa.html) con una app Android, entonces el identificador debe ser el del receptor! ¿?

de hecho la edición se realizo después

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de que realicé la última pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Decidí realizar una pregunta/respuesta en la que solo requería obtener el UUID 16 bytes del mismo dispositivo, lo cual hasta el día de hoy se puede obtener por reflexión, ya que lo común es obtener los UUID de los dispositivos conectados, esto para aportar al sitio y tal vez sea de ayuda a el OP y otros usuarios.

[¿Como obtener el UUID de bluetooth en un dispositivo Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149536/como-obtener-el-uuid-de-bluetooth-en-un-dispositivo-android)

Días después el OP confirmo que lo que deseaba era el identificador del dispositivo, aunque aún dudo sea lo que requiere.

Con respecto a :

> Sin embargo, luego vi que a posteriori se publicó la pregunta ¿Como
> obtener el UUID de bluetooth en un dispositivo Android?. Entonces, si
> fuera a reabrirla, ¿sería solamente para marcarla como duplicada?

**Es importante comentar que con la pregunta/respuesta que yo realicé y con la cual deseaba aportar a la comunidad, esta en realidad no sería un duplicado, [si reabre la pregunta del OP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149447/como-saber-la-uuid-android), esta NO puede marcarse como duplicada ya que el OP requiere lo que pregunta en `arduino`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso días después se realizo otra pregunta, donde se puede ver que esta usando `arduino` ahora con un HM-10!:

[Establecer conexión con módulo HM-10 con smartphone mediante bluetooth](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150404/establecer-conexi%C3%B3n-con-m%C3%B3dulo-hm-10-con-smartphone-mediante-bluetooth)

Con respecto a la pregunta en cuestión, Hay que recordar que **la pregunta esta en espera, lo cual indica que se puede reabrir**

Se requiere un poco de esfuerzo por parte de los usuarios nuevos, la mayoría se entera cuando agregamos comentarios acercar de revisar los documentos del [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), y trata de modificar la pregunta para que sea mas entendible y no de espacio a dudas, esta es la ayuda que requerimos de los usuarios que llevan algo de tiempo en la comunidad. En este caso el OP incluso aún no ha leído al menos el tour del sitio como le fue sugerido.

---

Con respecto al tiempo que se determina para actuar, últimamente hemos tenido una lluvia de preguntas de usuarios nuevos, en algunos caso ese tipo de preguntas si no son detalladas reciben respuestas que no dan solución en realidad, algunas son ediciones de la propia pregunta en el área de respuestas  y son marcadas como correctas lo cual contribuye a bajar la calidad de contenido en el sitio.

## Requerimos ayuda de los usuarios que llevan algo de tiempo y conocen el sitio para que nos apoyen con la tarea de guiar a los nuevos usuarios a formular adecuadamente preguntas y respuestas de acuerdo a lo especificado en el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tomarte el tiempo. Muy completa. Desde ya, mi comentario de "*muy directa*" se refiere a *luego* del comentario del autor y su edición a la pregunta, aclarando a qué UUID se está refiriendo; en el estado en el que la evalué para reapertura. En cuanto al IP, creo que sólo fue una analogía, pero estoy convencido de que no es lo que pide. Me queda la duda sobre lo que mencionás de la etiqueta. ¿No crees que al estar etiquetada [tag:android] [tag:arduino] se debe a un usuario inexperto que describe todo lo que usó, pero que hay que editarlas para corregirlas?

Comment: Además, quizás se malinterpretó que cuestioné el cierre, si es así, aclaro que me pareció excelente que se cierre rápido para evitar lo que estás mencionando e incentivar a que el autor mejore su pregunta. Ponerlo en espera era justamente para eso, para darle tiempo a que la edite, no? En ese sentido, me surge la pregunta: si esa pregunta te llevó a publicar (que es un gran aporte), no conviene esperar a ver si el autor edita, como lo hizo, o realizar un merge en su defecto?

Comment: Por último, respecto a tu reflexión al final, ¿de qué forma estás diciendo que requieren "*ayuda de los usuarios que llevan algo de tiempo...*"? O, específicamente, ¿de qué forma que no estemos haciendo actualmente? Quizás no estoy entendiendo el trasfondo del mensaje, o sería bueno tener más contribuciones en Meta por parte de moderadores acortando esta brecha y generando una continua interacción con el resto de la comunidad, enfocándonos en lo que importa y cerrando algunos de los pendientes. ¿No crees que estaría bueno tener opiniones y discusiones de casos más frecuentemente?

Comment: Gracias @Mariano dame un poco de tiempo y te respondo, estoy en proceso de "algo" en el trabajo :-\

Comment: Olvidate @Jorge! Disfrutá del feriado... La seguimos el lunes... Espero que quede claro que mi intención siempre apunta a mejorar la interacción en SOes, y siempre busco ser lo más constructivo posible, que no estoy criticando... En ese sentido, no hay ningún apuro en absoluto en este tema, que no es nada prioritario... relax, el sitio está funcionando mejor que nunca con el trabajo de los moderadores actuales, no hay necesidad de ver esto ahora.

Comment: Gracias Mariano, no tengo feriado hahaha así que tuve que laborar :), te comento que he realizado ediciones de preguntas y en 2 casos me arrepentí de editarlas ya que lo que pedía el OP al final me dí cuenta que no era lo que deseaba, y al final había modificado la pregunta, es un poco complicado en ocasiones ayudar cuando el OP no entiende muy bien o no esta seguro de lo que desea en realidad, así que en esta situación prefiero omitir un poco la edición hasta estar completamente seguro de lo que requiere.

Comment: Con respecto a los cierres (que en realidad son en espera) te puedo comentar que los 3 moderadores actuales somos flexibles, aún más con los nuevos usuarios, de hecho se dio tiempo para edición de la información, incluso realizar el tour, etc, por esa razón al siguiente día procedí a ponerla en espera pero la modificación a la pregunta se dio 2 días después de realizar la pregunta, esto a raíz de un comentario mio.

Comment: Con respecto a la ayuda, mi comentario es en relación a que veo que son pocos usuarios comparados el tamaño de la comunidad los que ayudan a los usuarios nuevos a realizar sus publicaciones correctamente, cada día veo nuevos usuarios que ayudan, pero me parece que necesitamos de más usuarios que ayuden a esta tarea, desde luego tu eres uno de los usuarios importantes que siempre están apoyando en esta y todas las tareas del sitio.

Comment: entendido (y aceptando la respuesta), muchísimas gracias!! Creo que el punto que comentaste recién ("*se dio tiempo para edición de la información*") es central en tu respuesta, y es lo que terminó de convencerme.. quizás convenga que lo agregues, no sé... En cuanto a la ayuda, ¿son pocos? (el [45% de los 3000+](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3284/127) parece bastante bien), pero es algo que, insisto, me encantaría ver más seguido publicado en Meta, con nuevas ideas de cómo podemos ayudar o mejorar... Felices pascuas y no-feriado! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que hay que hacer es recordar qué significa [[en espera]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

> #### ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas "en espera"?
>
> Las preguntas
> que necesitan trabajo adicional o que no encajan en este sitio pueden
> ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la comunidad.
> Mientras las preguntas estén en espera, no pueden ser respondidas,
> pero pueden ser editadas para hacerlas elegibles para reapertura.
>
> Las preguntas que son editadas dentro de cinco dias de haber sido
> puestas en espera son automáticamente agregadas a una cola de
> reapertura a revisión de la comunidad. Las preguntas que no sean
> reabiertas dentro de los cinco días cambiarán de [en espera] a
> [cerrada].

[en espera] es una oportunidad que se da a quien pregunta para mejorar su pregunta hasta alcanzar el nivel que se espera en SOes. Una oportunidad que dura cinco días.

Quien tenga interés en esta pregunta puede ayudar al autor original (AO) a mejorarla. En este caso es sin duda el camino apropiado puesto que el AO se muestra cooperativo y responde a los comentarios. Si pasados cinco días el AO no mejora su pregunta y esta queda [cerrada] entonces alguien que tenga interés en esta pregunta podría formular una nueva.

Lo que no debemos hacer es formular otra vez esta pregunta cuando no han transcurrido todavía esos 5 días de gracia. SOes es un sitio con un alto standard de calidad. Pero también es un sitio que pretende ser amistoso con los nuevos usuarios como pone de manifiesto la descripción de [en espera] al conceder 5 días para mejorar una pregunta. Si no concedemos esos cinco días los nuevos usuarios se van a sentir en un alto porcentaje rechazados y no se van a sentir animados a seguir usando el sitio. Es posible que nos perciban como un sitio elitista en que no es posible aprender de tus errores, mejorar y ver como tu contribución acaba siendo aceptada por la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Jose. Estás marcando puntos importantes a tener en cuenta: lo que se espera del autor y lo que se espera del resto de la comunidad.. Para completar, una pregunta cerrada y en espera son técnicamente lo mismo, donde lo único que cambia es la nomenclatura, para dar cuenta de que es reciente y que hay que tenerle *más* paciencia (técnicamente lo mismo, pero con reglas implícitas diferentes), como estás mencionando en tu respuesta, .. Pero, en cuanto a mi pregunta, ¿qué debería haber hecho en mi revisión?

Comment: @Mariano "Quien tenga interés en esta pregunta puede ayudar al autor original (AO) a mejorarla", lo cual incluye pero no se limita a ponerla en espera. Quien no tenga interés es suficiente con que vote para poner en espera en la revisión utilizando el motivo correcto.

Comment: entendido! :-) No me quedaba del todo claro, pero ahora sí, que estás diciendo que debería haber seleccionado "*Dejar cerrada*" (no por falta de interés, sino por falta de capacidad para mejorarla -ya que no sabría cómo mejorarla).

Comment: @Mariano En efecto [en espera] [es técnicamente lo mismo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) que [cerrado]: "*Las preguntas [en espera] seguirán no aceptando respuestas, y se comportarán idénticamente a las preguntas [cerradas]*". Pero el objetivo es distinto : "*El objetivo es comunicar mejor que las preguntas pueden ser mejoradas y reabiertas durante el periodo en que tienen una mejor oportunidad para que esto suceda*". Yo diría que el objetivo es más importante que la técnica.

Comment: Te aseguro que estamos diciendo lo mismo y solamente yo suelo usar el término "*cerrada*" para ambas, pero no dejo de distinguir la diferencia en el objetivo... De hecho, hasta argumentaría que las cerradas hace más de 5 días no dejan de ser salvables, y que cambiarlas de *en espera* a *cerradas* puede confundir ;-)

Comment: @Mariano Hubo un tiempo en que solo existía [cerrada]. Después, en junio de 2013, añadieron [en espera]. Quienes hicieron esto lo hicieron porque pensaban que este era un cambio que mejoraba el sitio : [Every “close” has its thorn: replace “close” with “on hold” for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d). Hubo quien no estaba de acuerdo. Hay quien, como tu, piensa que puede confundir. Pero es algo que se aceptó, implementó y hemos heredado en SOes. No podemos ignorarlo como un tecnicismo.

Comment: No creo que sea un tecnicismo; ese cambio en el título ayudó muchísimo a los usuarios que no conocen cómo funciona el sitio, y que entienden (un poco) mejor que no es insalvable... Sin embargo, desde la visión de un revisor que sabe cómo funciona el sitio, estoy convencido de que es mucho más importante entender *exactamente* cuánto pasó desde la publicación, desde el cierre, los comentarios que se dieron, las ediciones que hubo, entre muchas otras cosas, antes que simplificar el análisis a algo tan binario y arbitrario como más / menos que 5 días.