# Las auditorías de revisión no aparecen en el historial del perfil

Tags: bug, auditorías-de-revisión, actividad-reciente

[Reportado en Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318530/209901) el 19 de noviembre de 2018.

---

El [29 de octubre se activaron las auditorías de revisión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3723/83) (¡bien!) y al día siguiente, hoy 30 de octubre, ya me he topado con una (¡bien!):

> https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/122646
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso del caso es que si miro en mi perfil, sección ["revisiones"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=reviews), no aparece listada, pese a que [las auditorías de revisión sí aparecen en el perfil en los otros sitios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169161/209901).

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> <sub>(debería salir entre la de día 26 y la de día 30)</sub>

Nótese, de todos modos, que el 19 de noviembre pasé [una auditoría en una Primera publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/125945) y sí que aparece:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, ahora tengo un caso de Primera publicación que sí que aparece y una de Baja calidad que no.

Comment: En las herramientas de moderador, en el listado de auditorías sí que sale tu revisión

Comment: He mirado más a fondo y veo que la lista de auditorías de Publicaciones de baja calidad, no se ven reflejadas en los perfiles de ningun revisor. Tampoco la de Respuestas tardías, pero las demás colas sí...Aunque quizá se deba a que estas publicaciones están eliminadas desde hace días.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Sigue sucediendo esto?

Comment: @Juan sí, aún no salen. Nicolas me pidió en The Terminal que lo reportara en Meta.SE https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47607827#47607827. Lo intentaré hacer mañana

Comment: @fedorqui Ok, excelente.