# ¿Cómo mejorar la auditoría de revisiones?

Tags: discusión, auditorías-de-revisión, auditorías-de-revisión-discutibles

Me acaba de suceder algo curioso: Vi una primera respuesta en la cola de revisión, así que consulté la pregunta para estar en contexto y observé que la "respuesta" estaba publicada como un comentario.

Entonces regresé a la cola e indiqué que no se debía tomar ninguna acción, y el sistema me indicó que acababa de fallar la prueba de auditoría :( , que la respuesta estaba mal y que si necesitaba acciones a tomar.

No sabía de estas auditorías automáticas, me parecen geniales, pero debo decir que en este caso, al ver la respuesta como un comentario me dio la pauta para indicar que no se debía realizar ninguna acción (porque no revisamos comentarios).

Entiendo que originalmente la respuesta sí estaba en la sección de respuestas y precisamente porque era un comentario, un moderador la colocó como comentario y la eliminó como respuesta, entonces, como sugerencia para estas auditorías, quizá se podría mostrar la pregunta y la(s) respuesta(s) original(es) a los revisores, para que simule de forma idéntica el caso original y nos ayude a mejorar nuestras revisiones.

Comment: +1 por que también a mi me ha pasado  en 2 ocasiones, ahora cuando me topo con dichos casos prefiero el *omitir* si no de nuevo me dirá que fallé

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este caso particular no sé juzgarlo (pues no encuentro porque [Las auditorías de revisión no aparecen en el historial del perfil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3726/83), que creo que es un [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Ahora bien, si la respuesta ya no es tal, sino comentario movido allí por parte de un moderador, es una señal clara de que no era una respuesta, sino un comentario :)

Dicho lo cual...

> ¿Cómo mejorar la auditoría de revisiones?

Exactamente como hiciste: explicándolo en Meta, tal y como se explica en [¿Qué son las auditorías y cómo funcionan?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3727/83). Añade también una referencia a la revisión en sí, para que otra gente pueda comentar al respecto.
Creo que los moderadores tienen un botón para sacar una publicación de la lista de posibles auditorías.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la información