# ¿Qué son las auditorías y cómo funcionan?

Tags: soporte, faq, revisiones, auditorías-de-revisión

Desde el 29 de Octubre, [las auditorías están disponibles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3723/15855) en [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)!

Somos el 9º sitio en implementar esta funcionalidad.

---

A continuación la traducción de: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/368819)

- ¿Cuál es la finalidad de las auditorías?
- ¿Cómo funcionan?
- ¿Qué pasa si cometo errores?
- ¿Por qué el sistema esperaba que revisara negativamente una buena publicación, o favorablemente una mala?
- Una revisión es claramente una auditoría. ¿Debo reportarlo?
- ¿Cuentan las auditorías para la medalla de Revisor?
- ¿Sueñan los robo-revisores con ovejas eléctricas?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378)

Comment: En la respuesta, hay una lista de los sitios que tienen auditorias, pero no está completa.. sabeis donde mirar los 2 que faltan ?

Comment: se ve que puzzling dejó de tenerlo: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5852/5373 y el otro no sé (visto en las revisiones de la pregunta de MetaSE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Traducción de [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/368819)*

---

### ¿Cuál es la finalidad de este test?

El test, conocido como auditorías, está diseñado para ayudar a los nuevos revisores a depurar sus habilidades de moderación, así como dar pequeños *toques* a usuarios más experimentados que parecen no estar prestando la debida atención a las colas de revisión. Algunas personas tienden a votar a favor de todo lo que revisan sin considerar la calidad de las publicaciones. Publicaciones de muy baja calidad pero con alta puntuación son problemáticas en un sistema donde la mejor información ha de ser la que más puntuación tenga, por lo que se introducen auditorías para estar seguros de que los revisores están atentos.

Están activas actualmente en [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) y [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

### ¿Cómo funcionan las auditorías?

- **Primeras publicaciones**, **Publicaciones tardías** y **Publicaciones de baja calidad** - El test presenta al revisor una publicación que fue borrada y que se sabe de su baja calidad (reportada como spam, "no es una respuesta", o "muy baja calidad") o de su alta calidad calidad (muchos votos positivos, sin negativos, etc).
- **Votos de cierre** y **Votos de reapertura** - El test presenta al revisor una pregunta que el sistema determina que ha de estar abierta o cerrada basándose en diversos factores (muchos votos positivos sin votos de cierre, rápidamente cerrada sin respuestas, etc).
- **Ediciones sugeridas** - El test presenta al revisor una edición generada aleatoriamente utilizando el algoritmo "Cadena de Markov", que inserta varias palabras que aparentemente son de utilidad a primera vista pero que realmente no tienen mucho sentido o están pensadas para estropear la publicación.

Si un usuario pasa el test, se le informa de que lo ha pasado y se le agradece su tiempo y dedicación. Si un usuario falla el test, se le presenta un mensaje informándole de ese fallo y animándole a prestar más atención en el futuro.

El resultado es almacenado para su análisis. Sólo los moderadores con diamante (♦) o empleados de Stack Exchange pueden ver esa información. No es accesible tampoco para los usuarios con muy alta reputación.

### ¿Qué sucede si fallo?

Para la mayoria de personas, [nada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me/156942#comment452398_156942)(enlace en inglés). Se te dará información de por qué la publicación era inapropiada y qué tenías que haber hecho, y después se te permitirá seguir revisando.

> ¡ALTO! Mira y escucha.
>
> Esto fue una auditoría diseñada para ver si estabas prestando
> atención. No la aprobaste. No hay problemas importantes con esta
> pregunta. Deberías hacer clic en Dejar abierta, o hacer correcciones
> menores por medio de Editar.
>
> No te preocupes, ya hemos manejado esta publicación de la manera
> apropiada, pero tómate un minuto para leerla cuidadosamente teniendo
> en cuenta las pautas anteriores.

Multiples fallos, especialmente en un periodo corto de tiempo pueden [conllevar a una prohibición temporal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/why-am-i-getting-the-message-youve-failed-too-many-recent-review-audits#158675) (enlace en inglés) de una semana o más tiempo, dependiendo de la frecuencia de los errores. Stack Exchange analiza continuamente los resultados para determinar qué acción tomar en estos casos.

### ¿Por qué el sistema esperaba que revisara negativamente una buena publicación, o favorablemente una mala?

Las auditorías son *escogidas automáticamente*. El sistema no es perfecto, por lo que de vez en cuando una publicación se escapa de los filtros de detección causando así una auditoría mala, inválida o cuestionable.

Estas auditorías pueden dividirse en dos tipos:

**El sistema espera una revisión favorable de una mala publicación**

- El caso más común es en las colas de Baja calidad, No relacionado o preguntas que deberían cerrarse pero tienen votos positivos. Algunas veces los visitantes pueden dar voto positivo a las publicaciones sin pararse a pensar en las normas del sitio.
- Identificas una publicación como un duplicado exacto de otra más antigua, con muchos votos positivos. Para evitar que las auditorías sean obvias, el recuento de votos se muestra a cero y la tarjeta de usuario se muestra anónimo o como si fuera un usuario nuevo. Esto puede hacerte pensar que estás viendo un duplicado exacto cuando en realidad es la misma publicación.

**El sistema espera que haga una revisión no favorable de una buena publicación**

- Otros usuarios pueden haber votado negativo, lo cual puede significar que no están de acuerdo con lo escrito en la publicación en vez de pensar que es una mala publicación. Tú puedes tener otra opinión, o intentas juzgar objetivamente.
- Puede que la publicación haya sido marcada como spam como parte de un ataque de spam del que apenas unos usuarios conocen el detalle. En este caso, los moderadores pueden limpiar los reportes de spam, evitando así que la publicación sea usada en las auditorías.

*¡No te preocupes!* Que identifiques una mala auditoría significa que estás prestando atención y no eres el tipo de usuario que las auditorías pretenden *cazar*.

Si te encuentras con una mala auditoría, **crea una publicación en Meta** con las etiquetas [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte)[auditorías-de-revisión-discutibles](/questions/tagged/auditor%c3%adas-de-revisi%c3%b3n-discutibles) con un enlace a la auditoría o a la publicación que estabas revisando, y por qué estás en desacuerdo con la auditoría. Otros usuarios podrán votar para así contrarrestar la decisión automática que hizo que esa publicación fuera un tipo de auditoría equivocado (por ejemplo, vota negativo y cierra como No relacionado una pregunta que fue elegida como una auditoría favorable). Si recibes una prohibición para revisar como resultado de fallar una auditoría incorrecta, un moderador diamantado (♦), bajo su criterio, puede cancelar la suspensión o reducir su duración.

### Una revisión es obviamente una auditoría. ¿Debo reportarlo?

Hay muchas maneras de identificar una auditoría (por ejemplo, hacer click para ver la publicación, el usuario, el número de votos, etc.). Casi todas esas maneras implican investigar más a fondo la publicación. Con ello, has revisado más minuciosamente la publicación, lo cual es el fin último de las revisiones.

Como se dijo anteriormente, el principal objetivo de las auditorías es cazar a los *"robo-revisores"*, que sin pensar ni mirar revisan publicaciones, así como ayudar a nuevos revisores. Las auditorías fácilmente identificables ayudan a los revisores legítimos y también a los revisores novatos a depurar sus habilidades de moderación.

Por otro lado, si detectas a un usuario que parece estar jugando con el sistema (por ejemplo, están haciendo malas revisiones pero de alguna manera pasando las auditorías, usa scripts para identificar auditorías entre las revisiones, etc.) repórtalo en alguna de sus publicaciones para que un moderador pueda investigar la situación y proceder con lo oportuno, como un bloqueo en el sitio.

### ¿Cuentan las auditorías para la medalla de Revisor?

Las auditorías superadas cuentan como una revisión para las medallas de revisión. Una incorrecta auditoría no cuenta para las medallas pero tampoco disminuye tu progreso. Simplemente no suma nada.

### ¿Sueñan los robo-revisores con ovejas eléctricas?

Los robo-revisores no duermen. Ellos *esperan*.

#### Nota importante:

*La información aquí recogida es vulnerable a cambios ya que el sistema de revisiones puede ser modificado. Los cambios que tengan impacto en las mecánicas de este test, o las consecuencias de fallar las auditorías repetidamente serán reflejadas en esta publicación, pero no necesariamente de manera inmediata tras su implementación.*