# Voto de cierre rechazado para una pregunta duplicada ¿Quién lo arregla?

Tags: soporte, revisiones, auditorías-de-revisión, auditorías-de-revisión-discutibles, duplicadas

Estoy revisando en "votos de cierre" esta pregunta [¿Como determinar si una cadena se lee igual de derecha a izquierda, que de izquierda a derecha?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389085/determinar-letra-de-una-palabra-de-una-lista-en-python) que en realidad es un ejercicio de palíndromos.

Como el tema de los palíndromos ha sido abordado repetidas veces (ejemplo, [Como puedo invertir un string para chequear que sea palindrome con python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105904/como-puedo-invertir-un-string-para-chequear-que-sea-palindrome-con-python)) opté por cerrarla por duplicada, y obtuve esta reprimenda del sistema:

> ¡ALTO! Mira y escucha.
>
> Esto fue una auditoría diseñada para ver si estabas prestando
> atención. No la aprobaste. No hay problemas importantes con esta
> pregunta. Deberías hacer clic en Dejar abierta, o hacer correcciones
> menores por medio de Editar.
>
> No te preocupes, ya hemos manejado esta publicación de la manera
> apropiada, pero tómate un minuto para leerla cuidadosamente teniendo
> en cuenta las pautas anteriores.

¿Quién arregla esto?

Comment: Pienso que esa pregunta no está bien formulada, y tampoco es que tenga una excelente respuesta. Es mejor, tener tanto como una buena pregunta, como buenas respuestas, de esta manera se enriquece la publicación. Por lo tanto, considero que el ejemplo que pones no se puede considerar como duplicado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te pasó es que te encontraste con una auditoría de revisión, cuyo cometido y funcionamiento está explicado en [¿Qué son las auditorías y cómo funcionan?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3727/83).

La auditoría en concreto se ve en https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/233286. Como la pregunta tuvo en su momento buena acogida (puntaje 5, varias respuestas), el sistema la vio como buena y la metió en las auditorías como ejemplo "de lo que no debe cerrarse". Por ello, te tiró de las orejas automáticamente cuando dijiste que debía ser cerrada.

Creo que tu sugerencia de cerrar como duplicada es buena en general, pero que en este caso la pregunta que sugieres como principal no es mejor que la que quieres cerrar. Por ello, probablemente lo suyo sería cerrar en el sentido contrario (la vieja que apunte a la nueva).

El problema es que [votamos muy poco](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4189/83) y [no ponemos títulos descriptivos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83), por lo que el sistema de ordenación está algo roto y es bastante aleatorio. Del mismo modo que +5 en esta pregunta parece excesivo (la pregunta está bien, eso no lo discuto), en muchas otras tienen un puntaje menor siendo mejores, etc. Y esto repercute en que las auditorías cogen como "patrón oro" preguntas que lo mismo no lo son tanto.

---

Nótese por cierto que la pregunta tenía una respuesta tuya, no sé si lo viste. En tal caso, es recomendable no responder preguntas que pensamos que son duplicadas, para así concentrar el contenido en una única pregunta.

---

En cuanto a la pregunta sobre palíndromos en sí, lo suyo sería que se determinara cuál es la pregunta canónica y a partir de allí marcar el resto como duplicadas, tanto las pasadas como las que vendrán.

Comment: Recuerdo haber visto el mismo ejercicio varias veces y haberlo respondido al menos una vez, pero no lo pude encontrar de vuelta.

Comment: Ahora mismo tengo esta pregunta duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392166/hola-alguien-que-me-pueda-decir-mi-error-el-programa-pide-un-numero-y-lo-impri. La he visto antes pero no la puedo encontrar ... ¿alguién la encuentra?

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿[esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/389798/83)?

Comment: No, no es esa. La anterior tenía los números dibujados con "#".

Comment: Tranquilo @CandidMoe me ha pasado a preguntas que son de baja calidad e incluso estan cerradas y aceptadas